# Django. Populate user name or ID when user saving a model from web pages

Tags: django, user-input, userid, autosave

My **UserImg** Model has a **user** field that has **editable=False**.

I want this field to be automatically filled in with the user name when the **user is saved from web page**.

model.py

```
def upload_myimg_path(instance, filename):
    return 'documents/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.created_by.username, filename)

class UserImg(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('Created by'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_myimg_path, verbose_name=_('File'))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

forms.py

```
class UserImgForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserImg
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def createuserimg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserImgForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/users')
        else:
            return redirect('/accounts/')
    else:
        form = UserImgForm
        return render(request, 'accounts/user_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your view function to include current logged in user and make use of `@login_required` decorator to ensure that only logged in users can access this view :

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def createuserimg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserImgForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False) # <-- commit=False does not save to database
            obj.user = request.user # <-- this allows you to specify the user for your post
            obj.save() 
            return redirect('/accounts/users')
        # if the form did not validated, stay on the same page to display errors to your user
    else:
        form = UserImgForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/user_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: "user=request.user "It is highlighted yellow in my case. Nothing happens. After saving, the same page is updated and that's it.

Comment: For example, in the admin panel I did this (def save_model) and everything works 

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

Comment: Your have an ImageField so you need to add request.FILES to your form initialization

Comment: Also it seems that you are not displaying form errors in your HTML template

Comment: When saving this error occurs 
Exception Value:
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
the **user=request.user** show me yellow

Comment: commit=False allows you to modify the resulting object before it is actually saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

**correct answer** commit=False allows you to modify the resulting object before it is actually saved to the database. It`s works for me.
***Thank you very much for your help***

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def createuserimg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserImgForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            link = form.save(commit=False)
            link.user = request.user
            link.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/users')
        # if the form did not validated, stay on the same page to display errors to your user
    else:
        form = UserImgForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/user_form.html', {'form': form})
```